# Post on facebook only once per day

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-wall

Okay I'm using this script/code to post on user wall. But want to post only once per day, not everytime user visit the website.

```
$args = array(
    'message'   => '//',
    'link'      => 'http:////.com/',
    'caption'   => '//',
    'picture'   => 'http://www.//.jpg',
    'name'      => '//', 
);

$post_id = $facebook->api("/me/feed", "post", $args);
```

Comment: Cant you request the post you made by this api, and check if there is already a post on the same day?

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that ?

Comment: I looked on the facebook api site, but I couldnt find anything like I suggested. It seemed the obvious way, but you can also store a local database in which you keep track of the post history.

Comment: Can't you use the database?